# R argument is missing, with no default

Tags: r, csv

I want to calculate the log return of data . I define a function and want to load the data. but system always mentions second factor is missing. Otherwise it just calculate the log of row number.

```
#read data
data <- read.csv(file="E:/Lect-1-TradingTS.csv",header=TRUE)
mode(data)
p<-data["Price"]


#func1
func1 <- function(x1,x2)
{
  result <- log(x2)-log(x1)
  return(result)
} 


#calculate log return
log_return<-vector(mode="numeric", length=(nrow(data)-1))
for(i in 2:nrow(p))
{
  log_return[i-1] <- func1(p[(i-1):i])
}
```

> Error in func1(p[(i - 1):i]) : argument "x2" is missing, with no default

---

Comment: The Error tells you that `x2` is missing, which is what you called your second argument.  The "..., with no default" part is because you could define your function with `x2` having a default as in `func1 <- function(x1, x2 = 4) {...}`.

Comment: Perhaps you want `func1(p[i - 1],p[i])` rather than what you have.

Answer (score 2):

Your function `func1` was defined to accept two arguments, but you are passing it a single argument: the vector `p[(i-1):i]`, which has two elements but is still considered a single object. To fix this you need to pass two separate arguments, `p[i-1]` and `p[i]`. Alternatively, modify the definition of func1 to accept a two-element vector:

```
func1 <- function(v)
{
  x1 <- v[1]
  x2 <- v[2]
  result <- log(x2)-log(x1)
  return(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys，all your answers inspired me. I  think I found a solution.

```
log_return[i-1] <- func1(p[(i-1),"Price"],p[(i),"Price"])
```

Answer (score 0):

basically you do not need a func for those calcs in R
R's vectorization comes in handy in these cases

```
data <- read.csv(file="E:/Lect-1-TradingTS.csv",header=TRUE)
mode(data)
p <- data[["Price"]]
logrets <- log(p[2:length(p)]) - log(p[1:length(p)-1])
```

This vectorized computation will usually also heavily outperform any function you define "by hand".